# Catch unit tests in QT creator - multiple definitons of main

Tags: c, unit-testing, qt-creator, catch-unit-test

I would like to use Catch unit test framework for testing my projects. I read tutorial how to write tests, it was pretty simple. I tried to create really simple project in QT creator, which does include these files:

```
main.cpp
tests.cpp
factorial.cpp
factorial.h
catch.hpp
```

main.cpp :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "factorial.h"

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d", factorial(5));
    return 0;
}
```

tests.cpp :

```
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN
#include "catch.hpp"
#include "factorial.h"

TEST_CASE( "factorial on valid numbers", "[factorial]" ) {
    REQUIRE( factorial(1) == 1 );
    REQUIRE( factorial(5) == 120 );
    REQUIRE( factorial(10) == 3628800 );
}
```

factorial.cpp :

```
#include "factorial.h"

int factorial(int number)
{
    if(number < 0)
        return -1;
    int result = 1;
    for(int i = number; i > 0; i--)
        result *= i;
    return result;
}
```

factorial.h :

```
#ifndef FACTORIAL
#define FACTORIAL

int factorial(int number);

#endif // FACTORIAL
```

and catch.hpp is catch framework for unit tests

I am coding in C, not C++, extension ".cpp" is just because of catch, which is not working with files that have extension ".c"

There is one more file: testing.pro, which contains

Q

```
MAKE_CFLAGS += -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    factorial.cpp \
    tests.cpp

include(deployment.pri)
qtcAddDeployment()

HEADERS += \
    catch.hpp \
    factorial.h
```

This file was generated by QT creator.

Ok, and my problem is, that when I try to build this project, I get error: "multiple definition of main".

I get it. I have main in main.cpp file and also in tests.cpp. But I don't know, what should I do to make it work. I want to have project, with fully working main and file with tests, where I can test my functions. I searched almost everywhere. I guess I have to organize my project somehow in QT creator, but I have no idea how. I have no idea how it should work.

Thanks for advices

Answer (score 2):

You do indeed have two mains:

1. one in main.cpp
2. one provided by Catch, at your request, through the CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN macro definition.

The solution is to either remove the macro and use your main, or leave out your main to use the Catch-generated one.

More info here: [Catch: Supplying your own main()](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch/blob/master/docs/own-main.md)